# Connect TextEditor text count to ProgressView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, playgrounds

I'm creating a journaling app that would encourage the user to write at least a 100 characters in the Morning Pages section. I’d like to do that by placing a ProgressView at the bottom of a TextEditor. The progress bar would then go from 0 to 100% based on the user's input and stay at 100 if they write more than say 100 characters. The progress bar indicates the minimum chars needed to create the entry.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct AddNewEntryView: View {

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@EnvironmentObject var data : JournalEntriesData
@State var typeOfNewEntry : EntryType
@State var newEntry : Entry
@State var progressValue: Double = 0.0
let MIN_ENTRY_CHARS = 10

let detector = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
let publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

init(entryType: EntryType) {
    _typeOfNewEntry = State(initialValue: entryType)
    _newEntry = State(initialValue: Entry(type: entryType, text: ""))
    
    publisher = detector
        .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func limitTo(num: Double, maxNum: Double) -> Double {
    return num > maxNum ? maxNum : num
}

private func updateProgressBar() {
    print("char count", newEntry.text.count)
    progressValue = Double(newEntry.text.count / MIN_ENTRY_CHARS)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Text(newEntry.created, style: .date)
                .font(.headline)
            Section("Entry") {
                TextEditor(text: $newEntry.text)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .frame(minHeight: 80)
                    .onChange(of: newEntry.text) { _ in detector.send() }
                    .onReceive(publisher) {  updateProgressBar() 
                    }
                }
            ProgressView("Character count", value: $progressValue, total: 1.0)
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem {
            Button("Add") {
                data.entries.append(newEntry)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
      }
  }
}

struct AddNewEntryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddNewEntryView(entryType: .MORNING_PAGES)
    }
}
```

I almost got it now, but my ProgressView tells me that it cannot convert value of type Double to expected argument type Binding but I’m already using the $dollar sign there. It also says in the second error that initializer(in it value total) requires that binding Conforms to ‘BinaryFloatingPoint’. I’m new to Swift and getting a little lost in the typings here.

Comment: try: `ProgressView("Character count", value: progressValue, total: 1.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need binding, so fix is probably simple

```
ProgressView("Character count", value: progressValue, total: 1.0)
```

but you have complicated solution, I recommend to consider much simpler one using only `onChange` ('cause this calculation is fast and progress can be applied directly, w/o publisher). As well to reset `progressValue` directly after new entry added.

Here is simplified demo. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var progressValue: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section("Entry") {
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(minHeight: 80)
                        .onChange(of: text) { value in
                            if value.count <= 100 {
                                progressValue = Double(value.count) / 100.0
                            }
                        }
                }
                ProgressView("Character count", value: progressValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this partially works but the problem is the progress bar only updates when the floating point turns to 1.  My length calculation of var charactersCount: Double {
        Double(newEntry.text.count / MIN_ENTRY_CHARS)
    } just returns a 0 instead of a floating point 0.1, 0.3… etc

Comment: OK, I found out what's the problem here. Swift is being very picky when it comes to variable types and because I was dividing two INTs in its head, the result was therefore an int value dropping the decimal point. Changing the count and the limit to a double before division solved the issue. Dang, I spend too much time with JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Combine
    
    struct AddNewEntryView: View {
        @State private var myString: String = ""
        
        var charactersCount: Double {
            Double(myString.count)
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section("Entry") {
                        TextEditor(text: $myString)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        
                        VStack {
                            ProgressView("minimum character Required", value: charactersCount, total: 100)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section("summit") {
                        Button("Post") {
                            
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .disabled(charactersCount < 100)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct AddNewEntryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            AddNewEntryView()
        }
    }
```